# My second day on the job. How long have I been working here?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

if I today is my 2nd day in job and I am working. Somebody comes and asks me: How long have you been working here? (I mean he wants to know the number of days).

Should I say. I have been working here for 1 day or 2 days?

Should I count already today when it's not passed yet?

I don't want to use. This is my second day, because that is just a walkaround this question. I want to know the answer for How many days have you been working here.

I am not sure if to choose one day or 2 days if today is my second day. Should I count the on-going day or just the ones that are already passed?

Thanks for help and explanation

Comment: How is counting days relevant to English Language usage? On your second day, one easy answer is "since yesterday".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are limiting yourself to answering in days then the answer is "One day." A better answer would be "One day and three hours." but you haven't worked for two days until the second day is finished.

By analogy, if you are 25 years and 11 months old and I ask you your age, you would answer "Twenty-five" because you're not twenty-six until your birthday. You could give a more accurate answer like "twenty-five and eleven months" or "I'll be twenty-six next Tuesday." but if you're limited to years, it's "twenty-five".

It is only a problem in your example because the number of days is small and the error caused by giving the answer in days is proportionally greater. This is also the reason that the age of infants is normally given in months (or weeks) until they are about two years old.